# Unique constraints is not working in room database in android

Tags: android, android-room-relation

```
@Entity(tableName = "DailyGraphData", indices = [Index(value = arrayOf("lastTimeUsed","beginningTime"), unique = true)])
data class DailyGraphData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    var appName: String,
    var packageName: String,
    var totalAppTimeInForeground: Long? = 0L,
    var lastTimeUsed: String? = "",
    var beginningTime: String? ="",
    var endTime: String? = "",
    var isChild: Boolean
)
```

This is my entity class where beginningTime and lastTimeUsed i kept unique but when i try run app then first time i have 8 data is coming and storing in table  like below screen

[image]

now i am trying to insert again data with 10 value in which 8 are same as previous  2 more new value  but this time isChild will be 1 now when it  try to insert i don't know why its updating previous one value see in below screen.
[image]

you can see in this screen all previous value update ischild true and also two more value entry

what i want that if 8 record is already inserted in !ischild and lastTimeused and begtime is same when i try to insert another then it should insert just insert new lasttime used and beg time please help me what i am doing wrong

Comment: It looks like they are not updating, you're clearing table before inserting new values.

Answer (score 0):

It got solution i had to ignore if constraint is true .

I had given this :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

after updating

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
```

its not inserting new data if beg time and end time already there in database table